# Rhino 1.7r2-3 E4X "XML" is not defined

Tags: java, javascript, xml, rhino, e4x

I couldn't run following code using JDK 6.
It throws an exception:

Exception in thread "main" org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "XML" is not defined.

My environment is following: Ubuntu 11.04, JDK 6, Rhino 1.7R2 (also tested with Rhino 1.7R3)

```
    String script = "function abc(x) {var dd = new XML();}";
    Context context = Context.enter();
    try {
        ScriptableObject scope = context.initStandardObjects();
        Scriptable that = context.newObject(scope);

        Function fct = context.compileFunction(scope, script, "script", 1, null);
        Object result = fct.call(context, scope, that, new Object[] {2});

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        Context.exit();
    }
```

Comment: Can you verify that you are using the correct js.jar file for Mozilla Rhino. I tried your example on both Windows and Ubuntu Linux 11.04 using Eclipse and Rhino 1.7R2 and 1.7R3 and everything executed without any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem → in Rhino shell E4X works perfectly, but in embedded mode ­– ReferenceError: "XML" is not defined.

It was problem with old Xerces, I had 2.6.2 in my classpath when run my app. When I update it to 2.11 problem is gone.

```
$ java -cp js.jar:xerces-2.6.2.jar org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main
Rhino 1.7 release 3 2011 05 09
js> var x = <foo/>;
js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: ReferenceError: "XML" is not defined.
```

and

```
$ java -cp js.jar org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main
Rhino 1.7 release 3 2011 05 09
js> var x = <foo/>;
js> x.toXMLString();
<foo/>
```

Looks like when Rhino find Xerces, it uses it, instead of own mechanism to parse XML (when I start Shell with js.jar only in classpath).

Comment: I know )) I've resolved this issue.But thank you for respond anyway ))